# How to wire 2 different sets of panels to the same battery bank

Tags: solar-cell, watts, solar-charge-controller, multiple

My question is how do I add 2 different sets of panels to the same battery bank? I'm currently trying to design a solar array that will fit my tiny RV. Ive worked out how to fit 790w on my lil rig with 2 200w panels and 3 130w panels of the same type and company on my roof. But I'm not sure how to get them to play nice together. Is there a single charge controller that would be able to get them all to work together at peak efficiency? Or would getting 2 of the same charge controllers to handle each set of panels be a better idea? 1 set would be 400w together and the other 390w wired in parallel.